# Is there any way to change an "anchor point" of a CSS attribute? (not of an element itself)

Tags: html, css

Since I'm not a "real" programmer, I apologize if I'm writing something undesirable. Give me negative points, delete my post, tell me I'm stupid, but please answer, I will really appreciate it :)

I'm animating these elements by changing their height attributes. As you can see, the anchor point of the element is on its bottom left corner, but the attribute "height" has its own "default" anchor point. Can it be on the bottom of an element? Can i do anything to make it happen without using the negative value for the "height" attribute?

```js
function onmouseoverOne(){
  document.getElementById("one").style.height = "40px";
};
function onmouseoutOne(){
  document.getElementById("one").style.height = "50px";
};
function onmouseoverTwo(){
  document.getElementById("two").style.height = "40px";
};
function onmouseoutTwo(){
  document.getElementById("two").style.height = "50px";
};
function onmouseoverThree(){
  document.getElementById("three").style.height = "40px";
};
function onmouseoutThree(){
  document.getElementById("three").style.height = "50px";
};
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
*{padding: 0;margin: 0;}
body {
  background-color:white;
}
#container {position:fixed; top:50px; left:100px; width:300px; height:100px; z-index:1;}
#container p{position:absolute; top:100px; left:0px;z-index:3;}
#one {position:absolute; top:50px; left:0px; width:100px; height:50px; background-color:green; z-index:2; cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
        transition: all 300ms linear;
-webkit-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
   -moz-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
        tranform: translate(0,-50px);
}
#two {position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px; width:100px; height:50px; background-color:blue;  z-index:2; cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
        transition: all 300ms linear;
-webkit-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
   -moz-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
        tranform: translate(0,-50px);
}
#three {position:absolute; top:50px; left:200px;  width:100px; height:50px; background-color:purple; z-index:2; cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
   -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
        transition: all 300ms linear;
-webkit-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
   -moz-tranform: translate(0,-50px);
        tranform: translate(0,-50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one"   onmouseover = "onmouseoverOne()"   onmouseout = "onmouseoutOne()"></div>   
  <div id="two"   onmouseover = "onmouseoverTwo()"   onmouseout = "onmouseoutTwo()"></div> 
  <div id="three" onmouseover = "onmouseoverThree()" onmouseout = "onmouseoutThree()"></div>
  <p>pls mouseover</p>
</div>
```

here is a diagram
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLzdd.jpg

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit because I am not sure what you want to do ... You don't want to hardcode the heights for divs #one #two #three? What do you mean by "anchor point"?

Comment: To try to simplify, I want to animate the height attributes "upwards" (element rises from bottom to top) and not "downwards" like in my example.... but without using negative values for the "height" cause for some reason it messes up my divs.

Comment: Here is a diagram http://i.imgur.com/Pf7SzNk.jpg?1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for the first tab (you only have to apply it to the others by changing the correct heights).

Edit: Explanation

What you want to do is to remove the `height` and use `margin-top` css property instead. Calculate `marginTop = initialHeight - wantedHeight` and apply it `onmouseoverOne()` Then `onmouseoutOne()` reset to initial values again.

```
function onmouseoverOne(){  
  document.getElementById("one").style.height = "40px";
  document.getElementById("one").style.marginTop = "10px";  
};

function onmouseoutOne(){
  document.getElementById("one").style.marginTop = "0px";
  document.getElementById("one").style.height = "50px";
};
```